# what does mean "_Default" partial class and inherited class "System.Web.UI.Page"

Tags: asp.net

I just wanted to know the details that in asp.net, the code behind comes with a partial class "_Default" and this class also inherit from a other class "Page".

what all the functionality in "Page" class and what does mean "_Default" class....why this class is partial.

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**What does _Default mean and why it is a partial class?**

The class `_Default` represents the code behind for your Default.aspx page. It is partial so that it can be declared in multiple class file. In this case, all the control declarations are auto generated in another partial class for `_Default`. Which you normally can't see, ideally because you don't need to.

Here is how this is defined by MSDN.

> Note that the code-behind source file declares a partial class that
>   inherits from a base page class. The base page class can be Page, or
>   it can be another class that derives from Page. Furthermore, note that
>   the partial class allows the code-behind file to use controls defined
>   on the page without the need to define them as field members.

**Why inherit from Page?**

It inherits from page so you can use the features of the already implemented [`Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class. This means you can access query strings, complete redirects and many many more features, check out the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) for a full list (there's hundreds).

Comment: This is exactly true. It is NOT partial *because* it inherits from the Page class !! Partial is just a way to declare a class in separate source files. Now, it is typically used for instance along with code generation so you can extend the class by with your own properties and members without modifying the auto-generated source. This way you can re-generate the code without loosing your alterations.